# Google Polymer for Android native app

Tags: android, polymer, native

Google Polymer looks like a simple way to make material designed web pages. I am developing a native Android application and would like to make it material designed. My question is, can I use Polymer for native Android applications?

Comment: You can think about if your application could be an web application instead of a native app (Like... did it use hard coded access to hardware things, Like use the camera with openCV?)
If yes, your application can be an web application, then you can make a progressive web app, this will be added to the android user's home screen, can be openned off-line, and will have all the native app feelling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot use Polymer to build a truly "native" Android app. Although there are frameworks such as [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) which would allow you to build an app using web technologies and then compile into an Android app.

If your goal is to make an app that follows material design patterns, I suggest you get started by reading the official documentation on the subject: [Creating Apps with Material Design](http://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

Polymer is a JavaScript Framework that implements web-specific standards for the front-end.

And JavaScript is not the native language of Android so Polymer cannot be used to build Native Apps (using Java) using Meterial Design.

But on the other hand you can build entire applications using HTML5 with the help of some technologies like Cordova and PhoneGap.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can make native mobile apps with Polymer, thanks to [**Polymer Native**](https://github.com/PixelsCommander/polymer-native).

Answer (score 1):

If you are into native Android then you should use Android Official Appcompat Library(which is default) but it lacks backport of some Mateial elements and features( [**Official Tutorial**](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)). if you really need to implement the elements which Appcompat lacks you can use any third party librarie like [MaterialEverywhere](http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/) or [this](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) or you can find [here](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=material%20android%20library) if something is really availabe in the world.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we cannot create pure native apps, But we can convert web apps developed in HTML, CSS, JS which is to run in a browser. Cordrava helps to convert the web app source to an apk file which can be installed in an Android devices as a native app. Cordrava makes the web app to run in the web view of android. 
A good example tutorial below provided by [Ashraff Hathibelagal](http://tutsplus.com/authors/ashraff-hathibelagal/)

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-to-do-list-app-with-polymer-and-cordova--cms-25434